# trouble defining "Invalid" values from room dict

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop, key-value-store

```
def nextroom(currentloc, direction):
    rooms = {
        'Bedroom': {'North': 'Parents Office', 'South': 'Living-room', 'East': 'Kitchen', 'West': 'Bathroom', 'Item': 'Invalid'},
        'Parents Office': {'North': 'Invalid','South': 'Bedroom', 'East': 'Dads Man Cave', 'West': 'Invalid', 'Item': 'Golf Club'},
        'Bathroom': {'North': 'invalid', 'South': 'Invalid', 'East': 'Bedroom', 'West': 'Invalid', 'Item': 'Hand Soap'},
        'Living-room': {'North': 'Bedroom', 'South': 'Invalid', 'East': 'Invalid', 'West': 'Invalid', 'Item': 'Nerf Gun'},
        'Dining-room': {'North': 'invalid', 'South': 'Invalid', 'East': 'Invalid',  'West': 'Living-room', 'Item': 'Bucket of Marbles'},
        'Kitchen': {'North': 'Garage', 'South': 'Invalid', 'East': 'Invalid',   'West': 'Bedroom', 'Item': 'Handcuffs' },
        'Garage': {'North': 'invalid', 'South': 'Kitchen', 'East': 'Invalid', 'West': 'Invalid', 'Item': 'Rc Car'},
        'Dads Man Cave': {'North': 'invalid', 'South': 'Invalid', 'East': 'Invalid', 'West': 'Parents Office', 'Item': 'Infiltrator'}
}
    return rooms[currentloc][direction]


def player_stat(location):
    rooms = {
        'Bedroom': {'North': 'Parents Office', 'South': 'Living-room', 'East': 'Kitchen', 'West': 'Bathroom', 'Item': 'Invalid'},
        'Parents Office': {'North': 'Invalid', 'South': 'Bedroom', 'East': 'Dads Man Cave', 'West': 'Invalid','Item': 'Golf Club'},
        'Bathroom': {'North': 'invalid', 'South': 'Invalid', 'East': 'Bedroom', 'West': 'Invalid', 'Item': 'Hand Soap'},
        'Living-room': {'North': 'Bedroom', 'South': 'Invalid', 'East': 'Invalid', 'West': 'Invalid', 'Item': 'Nerf Gun'},
        'Dining-room': {'North': 'invalid', 'South': 'Invalid', 'East': 'Invalid', 'West': 'Living-room', 'Item': 'Bucket of Marbles'},
        'Kitchen': {'North': 'Garage', 'South': 'Invalid', 'East': 'Invalid', 'West': 'Bedroom', 'Item': 'Handcuffs'},
        'Garage': {'North': 'invalid', 'South': 'Kitchen', 'East': 'Invalid', 'West': 'Invalid', 'Item': 'Rc Car'},
        'Dads Man Cave': {'North': 'invalid', 'South': 'Invalid', 'East': 'Invalid', 'West': 'Parents Office', 'Item': 'Infiltrator'}
}

    print('----------------------------')
    print('You are in {} with {}'.format(location, rooms[location]['Item']))
    print('----------------------------')


def play():
     currentRoom = 'Bedroom'
     while currentRoom != 'Exit' or 'exit':
         player_move = input('Enter your move:\n')
         if player_move == 'Exit' or player_move == 'exit':
            currentRoom = 'Exit'
            print('Play again soon!')
         elif player_move == 'South' or player_move == 'south':
            currentRoom = nextroom(currentRoom, 'South')
            player_stat(currentRoom)
         elif player_move == 'North' or player_move == 'north':
            currentRoom = nextroom(currentRoom, 'North')
            player_stat(currentRoom)
         elif player_move == 'West' or player_move == 'west':
            currentRoom = nextroom(currentRoom, 'West')
            player_stat(currentRoom)
         elif player_move == 'East' or player_move == 'east':
            currentRoom = nextroom(currentRoom, 'East')
            player_stat(currentRoom)
```

Above is part of coding from text based game I am creating. I am having trouble defining the "invalid" values in the rooms dictionary in my while loop. When invalid rooms are accessed by user I want it to print a str.

Thank you

below is the error I get from my side when I try to access a room ('North' : 'Invalid')

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jacenduplain/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/1.py", line     111, in <module>
    play()
  File "/Users/jacenduplain/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/1.py", line     91, in play
    player_stat(currentRoom)
  File "/Users/jacenduplain/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/1.py", line     75, in player_stat
    print('You are in {} with {}'.format(location, rooms[location].   ['Item']))
KeyError: 'Invalid'
```

Comment: `currentRoom != 'Exit' or 'exit'` should be `currentRoom != 'Exit' and currentRoom != 'exit':`

Comment: But instead of doing two tests, why not just `currentRoom.lower() != 'exit'`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: Great point, I will edit that into my code. Thanks.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon I don't think that's what the question is about, it's an unrelated bug.

Comment: Just add an `else:` block that prints that the move is invalid.

Comment: Brian -- it does get the wheels turning, I will be looking into this.

Comment: If that doesn't answer your question, could you add some details about exactly what is going wrong? E.g. expected and actual output for a given input.

Comment: You don't even need the `while` condition. Use `while True:` and then add `break` when it matches `exit`.

Comment: Oh, your question is about what to do when `nextroom()` returns `invalid`

Comment: Barmar -- Correct! sorry I didn't state that more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Change `nextroom()` to check whether it's an invalid room. If it is, it can print a message and return the original room.

```
def nextroom(currentloc, direction):
    rooms = {
        'Bedroom': {'North': 'Parents Office', 'South': 'Living-room', 'East': 'Kitchen', 'West': 'Bathroom', 'Item': 'Invalid'},
        'Parents Office': {'North': 'Invalid','South': 'Bedroom', 'East': 'Dads Man Cave', 'West': 'Invalid', 'Item': 'Golf Club'},
        'Bathroom': {'North': 'invalid', 'South': 'Invalid', 'East': 'Bedroom', 'West': 'Invalid', 'Item': 'Hand Soap'},
        'Living-room': {'North': 'Bedroom', 'South': 'Invalid', 'East': 'Invalid', 'West': 'Invalid', 'Item': 'Nerf Gun'},
        'Dining-room': {'North': 'invalid', 'South': 'Invalid', 'East': 'Invalid',  'West': 'Living-room', 'Item': 'Bucket of Marbles'},
        'Kitchen': {'North': 'Garage', 'South': 'Invalid', 'East': 'Invalid',   'West': 'Bedroom', 'Item': 'Handcuffs' },
        'Garage': {'North': 'invalid', 'South': 'Kitchen', 'East': 'Invalid', 'West': 'Invalid', 'Item': 'Rc Car'},
        'Dads Man Cave': {'North': 'invalid', 'South': 'Invalid', 'East': 'Invalid', 'West': 'Parents Office', 'Item': 'Infiltrator'}
    }
    next = rooms[currentloc][direction]
    if next.lower() == 'invalid':
        print("You can't go that direction!")
        return currentloc
    else:
        return next
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much! I will be testing this out, thanks for the speedy guidance.